# How to convert a JSON string to array by Groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

How to take the value of this JSON and create a array in Groovy? For example

```json
{
"ITAB": [
"1",
"12",
"123",
"1234",
"12345"
]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonSlurper`.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper   
def json = """{"ITAB": [
"1",
"12",
"123",
"1234",
"12345"
]
}"""

assert ['1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345'] == new JsonSlurper().parseText(json).ITAB
```